# Accessing HashMap List element for a Repeated Int parameter

Tags: scala, function

I am very new to Scala and am building a function to calculate average student grades. The problem is, I created a HashMap with the student's name as the key with the grade values in a List as presented below

```
var gradeMap = Map("John" -> List(10,30,60,78,90,45,33))
```

The code for the function is this

```
  def Count(name: String, i:Int*) = {
    val pass: Double = i.filter(_ >=40).reduceLeft(_+_)/7 //
    val fail: Double = i.filter(_ < 40).reduceLeft(_+_)/7

    println(s"Student name: $name")
    println(s"Pass average: $pass")
    println(s"Fail average: $fail")
  }
```

I am trying to call the function as follows

`Count("John", gradeMap("John"))`

I tried Googling all day but I couldn't find a fix. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You can `Count("John", gradeMap("John") : _*)` or change the function signature to `def count(name: String, i: Seq[Int]): Unit = { ... }`. - PS: Not intention of sounding rude, but if this really took you all day, IMHO, you would be better to start with some tutorials or reading an introductory book or watching a course about Scala. This is just basic syntax / types.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. Works a massive treat. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're mixing two things that might seem similar but are not.

Having a map `String -> List[Int]` obviously means that doing `gradeMap("John")` gives you back a `List[Int]` (namely `List(10, 30, 60, 78, 90, 45, 33)`).

Your `Count` function instead asks for a so-called `varargs` parameter. This means you can pass your function one or more `Int`s. 
This is very different than passing a `List[Int]`.

So my suggestion would to change the function signature to `name: String, i: List[Int]`.

Note: try and name functions lowercase as that's Scala's default convention.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I appreciate the help immensely.

Comment: Accept the answer if it was useful.